# Programmatically searching for a text phrase in a Word document using C# but without Word Interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, text-search

I am looking for a method via C# to programmatically search for Word documents in a given folder that contain a specific text phrase. The program needs to be able to work without using Word Interop as it may be running on a server.

I have tried to search for solutions, but anything I find is very old and based on outdated versions of libraries and applications.

Comment: have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/word-processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) is probably your best bet.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false);
string content = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText;

if (content.Contains("phraseToSearch"))
{
    //do your thing
}   

doc.Close();
```